# Dataframe to fill in with missing values - complete() function

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, missing-data

I have an initial dataframe `df`  with 30 samples, with the following columns:

1. ID : chr "ACAGA" "GTCGA" "GTCGA" "ACAGT" ...
2. value : num  1.40 2.28 0.39 1.32 ..
3. dimension : int  119 716 626 114 ...

In this `df` dataframe, each ID is repeated multiple times.

I have then created a second dataframe named `df2`, selecting just those IDs that have a value > 1.3 and summing all the dimensions for each ID.

```
df2 = df[value > 1.3, .(dim = sum(dimension)), by = ID]
```

The new dataframe `df2` doesn't have all the initial IDs from `df`. In particular, there are 4 missing IDs that I would like to add in `df2` dataframe and set their `dim` value as 0.

I've tried to use `complete()` function from tidyr package, but the code I've written doesn't work:

```
complete(df2, dim, fill = list(count = 0))
```

Do you know how should I use complete() to achieve the result I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `complete` as follows -

```
df2 <- tidyr::complete(df2, ID = unique(df$ID), fill = list(dim = 0))
```